# What is the definition of linear equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

All books I looked through write that the linear equation is the equation that has a from:

$$a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\dots+a_nx_n=b$$

But is this really the definition of a linear equation? I thought that the definition should be the form of linear mapping. Like,

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
$$f(ax)=af(x)$$

What is the definition of a linear equation?

Comment: If we have a vector $\vec a = \langle a_1, ..., a_n\rangle$ then the linear equation you wrote is equivalent to solving $$f(\vec x) = b$$ where $f(\vec x) = \vec a \cdot \vec x$. And $f$ is exactly a linear function.

Comment: I believe that the first form is the true definition of a linear equation.

Answer (score 3):

The second defines a *linear function*, not a linear equation. For a matrix $A$, the function $f(x)=Ax$ is linear. For $A=(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)$ and $x=(x_1,\ldots,x_n)^T$, $Ax=a_1x_1+\cdots +a_nx_n$.

Comment: and linear function = linear function is a linear equation

Answer (score 2):

There are two different  concepts here.

$1)$  A  linear equation such as

$$ a_1x_1+a_2x_2+\dots+a_nx_n=b$$ where the variables appear in the first degree.

$2)$ A linear transformation  which satisfies

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$

$$f(ax)=af(x)$$

For example $$2x+3y=10$$ is a linear equation.

On the other hand $$f(x) = 4x $$ is a linear function or linear transformation.